# how to add a slash and query string after subdomain in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently have a wildcard subdomain setup also using the htaccess code.
this works great

But now i also want users to able to go to 
`subdomain.domain.com/settings/` 
or `subdomain.domain.com/settings`

i'll need to pass a second query string to index.php

How i can do that?

Thanks.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+).domain.com
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?subdomain=%1 [L]
```

tagert url   :   `/index.php?subdomain=%1&page=settings`

"settings" would be replaced by what user enters, it could be login  or register or dashboard.  That would be the page to go to.

Comment: Please give an example of what the target URL would look like with an additional query string parameter. Something like `/index.php?subdomain=%1&path=settings` ??

Comment: Is it ok if an empty `page=` is submitted, or does the receiving code expect that `page=` not be present at all if it is empty?

Comment: it can be empty as i do the checking in index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is acceptable for `index.php` to receive an *empty* value for `page`, you can merely change the one `RewriteRule` you have to accommodate it, expecting that if not supplied, `$_GET['page']` will be present as an empty string:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+).domain.com
# Don't send index.php into a rewrite loop
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# Capture page in $1, everything up to the first / or the end $
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ /index.php?subdomain=%1&page=$1 [L]
```

The pattern `([^/]*)` will match anything up to the first `/`, if there is anything present.  The `/?` allows for an optional trailing slash. Given this pattern, any of these would match, but the final two would result in an empty `$_GET['page']`

- `subdomain.example.com/settings`
- `subdomain.example.com/settings/`
- `subdomain.example.com/`
- `subdomain.example.com`

Comment: i get Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: @ASH Sorry, I remembered when I woke up this morning that you would also need a `RewriteCond` to prevent `index.php` from being rewritten in an endless loop. Added above.

Comment: @ASH Glad to help. Good luck to you.